# Bad request error while adding a lookup GUID field in CRM database using Web API

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dotnet-httpclient, http-status-code-400, dynamics-crm-webapi

I want to insert a new record in CRM's custom entity where one of the fields is of lookup type i.e. `new_contactid` and it is dependent on the `contact` entity.

I have also referred [Set Values of all Data Types using Web API in Dynamics CRM Through C#](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crminogic/archive/2016/04/13/set-values-of-all-data-types-using-web-api-in-dynamics-crm-through-c).

My **JSON** data is as below:

`{
    "new_transactionnumber":"114",
    "new_transactionamount":650,
    "new_transactiondate":"2018-01-29T15:01:00.000Z", 
    "new_contactid_contact@odata.bind":"/contacts(afb9e006-6be5-e711-80ed-bef806786223)", 
    "new_moveid_new_move@odata.bind":"/new_moves(896f2dcd-b2fa-e711-80ef-bef806786223)"
}`

Here, last 2 fields are for lookup GUID. Original field names are:

- new_contactid
- new_moveid

What I have added to the end is it's **primary key's entity name**.

Please let me know if I am missing anything in here.

**EDIT 1**:
Below is the references I found in OData file for lookup field:

```
<NavigationProperty Name="new_contact_new_transaction_contactid" Type="Collection(mscrm.new_transaction)" Partner="new_contactid" />

<Property Name="_new_contactid_value" Type="Edm.Guid">
  <Annotation Term="Org.OData.Core.V1.Description" String="ContactId" />
  <Annotation Term="Org.OData.Core.V1.Computed" Bool="true" />
  <Annotation Term="Org.OData.Core.V1.Permissions">
    <EnumMember>Org.OData.Core.V1.PermissionType/Read</EnumMember>
  </Annotation>
</Property>

<NavigationProperty Name="new_contactid" Type="mscrm.contact" Nullable="false" Partner="new_contact_new_transaction_contactid">
  <ReferentialConstraint Property="_new_contactid_value" ReferencedProperty="contactid" />
</NavigationProperty>

<NavigationPropertyBinding Path="new_contact_new_transaction_contactid" Target="new_transactions" />

<NavigationPropertyBinding Path="new_contactid" Target="contacts" />
```

**EDIT 2**: *These lookup fields are GUID bound to other existing entity's primary key.*

Comment: What error message do you receive? As a potential answer, consider whether your call is case-sensitive as [this post](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmtipsfromadeveloper/archive/2017/06/21/know-how-set-a-lookup-value-on-create-update-of-a-record-using-mscrm-webapi-an-undeclared-property-error) suggests it could be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the Navigation property will use the Schema Name (Camel casing) not the Logical name (pascal casing).

Please refer the comment in [this blog post](http://www.inogic.com/blog/2016/02/set-values-of-all-data-types-using-web-api-in-dynamics-crm/) comments section & change appropriately:

> Please follow the steps listed below :
>
> Step 1 : Goto Cutomization  Developer Resource.
>
> Step 2 : Click to “Download Odata Metadata” link and Download the
>   same.
>
> Step 3 : Once Download, open it and find out name of lookup attribute
>   ( i.e. “new_qualifiedleadid”) and check its casing.
>
> Step 4 : Verify it with the value which you are setting in the code it
>   should be same.

Comment: I have edited the question with references I have found for lookup field `new_contactid` in OData file.

Comment: Yes, that solved my issue. `new_contactid` was correct but for **Move Id** I was writing `new_moveid` while it should be `new_MoveId` as per OData.